# Why await function is showing an error in-spite of writing the same code as the documentation?

Tags: sendgrid, velo

I'm currently developing an Elearning calculator. To mail the calculated summary to the users, I'm using SendGrid for the same. I followed the SendGrid documentation and have added the email.jsw file in the backend of my website. But, in spite of copying the same code, I'm getting an error in it. Here is the code-

```
//email.jsw

import {sendWithService} from 'backend/sendGrid';
import wixSecretsBackend from 'wix-secrets-backend';

export function sendEmail(subject, body) {
  const sendGridSecret = JSON.parse(await wixSecretsBackend.getSecret('sendGridSecret'));
  const key = sendGridSecret.key;
  const sender = sendGridSecret.senderEmail;  
  const recipient = "some-email-address@some-domain.com";
  return sendWithService(key, sender, recipient, subject, body);
}

export function sendEmailWithRecipient(subject, body, recipient) {
  const sendGridSecret = JSON.parse(await wixSecretsBackend.getSecret('sendGridSecret'));
  const key = sendGridSecret.key;
  const sender = sendGridSecret.senderEmail;
  return sendWithService(key, sender, recipient, subject, body);
}
```

I tried writing the above code. But, the emails can't be sent. Here the word "await" displays an error: "'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of the modules." Here is the link to the SendGrid documentation- https://support.wix.com/en/article/velo-tutorial-sending-an-email-on-form-submission. Can someone please help me understand why the await function is showing an error in spite of writing the same code as the documentation, or am I missing something?